# Alternative Method to Retrieve Windows Product Key

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, product-key

I already know that there are certain methods to get Windows Product Key such as third-party software detection, from system information on desktop, or if operating system was installed already on device, there is an official Windows product sticker.

My old laptop's GPU died and when I boot it up it works fine. I do not have an HDMI cable to hook it up to my TV. I have only SATA-USB cable to connect its HDD to my new laptop so that I can access my files. I cannot install third-party softwares as you can guess because screen is black. Plus, the Windows Product Key sticker on the bottom of my laptop has some missing keys due to worn-out over time.

Here comes my questions. Is there a way to retrieve my Windows Product Key from the HDD as in acquiring certain file(s) with txt or other kinds of extension? Can I use that HDD on which Windows 7 has already been installed to boot up on a virtual machine so that I can access my product key?

Answer (score -1):

The tag reads Windows 7, which means you might be in luck. Win 8 and up have complications preventing your objective.

On the [How-To Geek web site](https://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/), there's a product recommendation specific to your question. The page covers other methods, not applicable. Scroll down to the "even if you can't boot your PC" section, which is also followed by a no-software "have to be able to boot" method.

The recommendation is to use a program called [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to retrieve the information.

From How-To Geek:

> If you want to recover a key from a dead computer, you can hook up the
> hard drive to a working PC, and then run ProduKey and use File >
> Select Source to point to the external Windows directory. You can then
> grab the keys from that computer easily.

[image: ProduKey screen cap]

Comment: I just tried this option, but it did not work out as the article warns: _"Note: the NirSoft keyfinder won’t always work for OEM computers..."_

Comment: As a last resort I ran ProduKey software as administrator and tried that way by loading keys from an external source option. It found a Windows 7 key though. I am not sure because the device I run the software on has been upgraded from Windows 7. I do not know if that key is the Win 7 key of the device I am using right now.

Comment: @BurakKaraosmanoğlu you can use the Win7 (or win8) key with a Windows 10 installation. But you may have trouble activating that Win10 installation because the key was previously used with different hardware. Those “Free upgrade win7 to win10” keys are considered to be OEM keys that are not supposed to be transferable to other hardware. It often works though.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to give it a try since I recently upgraded an old laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10.